# Ext. HDD I/O Error - suspends, power issues?

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, hard-drive

My external USB HDD becomes repeatedly inaccessible after a long time of usage/idleness. The same thing happened before with a very old disk and I thought it was just failing. But I do have the same issue with a new set-up.

I get errors like the following and I have to physically remove the disk from its power supply to get it to work again.

```
usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[sda] Unhandled error code
```

[Full log](http://openpaste.org/6c40F65F)

I'm suspecting some kind of power issue - I heard old RPis do have them.
The RPi is plugged into a 2 slot PSU, the HDD is connected with a Y-cable to the same PSU and the RPi. I thought I might get actually less voltage problems when they draw from the same source. I also tried a powered USB hub, but that didn't quite work.

My problem is similar to [this Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/periodically-losing-connection-to-external-hard-drive), but that persons solution is my current state of affairs...

There is also a very old thread on the Ubuntu forums regarding usbcore module options *autosuspend* and *old_scheme_first* [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789&page=2)
I didn't test that yet, because it takes several hours or days for the problem to occur...

Any ideas? Or is it fixed for newer versions of Rpi? Some additional infos:

RPi B, Revision: 0002 (pre-ordered it when it came out)

External USB HDD Western Digital Elements 2,5":

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1058:10a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

Mounted with:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/athena ext4
rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=30,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: What's the amperage on the PSU?  You don't have to wait for the problem to happen before you try the `old_scheme_first` and `autosuspend` thing although you probably have to reconnect the drive afterward.  I would try just the first one and if it happens again, then turn off the autosuspend.

Comment: It's 1A. Yes, I can try it now, but I'll have to wait and see if it has any effect :)

Comment: **That PSU is too small!** The pi is going to consume 700+ mA, and the drive could be up to 500.  Something is bound to brown out occasionally.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. But I just stress tested my pi (with 'stress'), getting the cpu utilization to 100% for a while and using the HDD via rsync. That should max out the PSU, but it worked just fine. All stable 0.o

Comment: Did you get a solution for this yet. I have the same problem?

Comment: Not really. The problem occured much less often, but I've used the pi less aswell. It might really just be the PSU. I've just moved and the Pi is in a box somewhere. I might try it with a bigger one eventually.